# AWS ECS Service for Wordpress

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I created a service for wordpress on AWS ECS with the following container definitions

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "wordpress",
      "links": [
        "mysql"
      ],
      "image": "wordpress",
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 0,
          "hostPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "memory": 250,
      "cpu": 10
    },
    {
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD",
          "value": "password"
        }
      ],
      "name": "mysql",
      "image": "mysql",
      "cpu": 10,
      "memory": 250,
      "essential": true
    }
  ],
  "family": "wordpress"
}
```

Then went over to the public IP and completed the Wordpress installation. I also added a few posts.

But now, when I update the service to use a an updated task definition (Updated mysql container image)

```
"image": "mysql:latest"
```

I loose all the posts created and data and Wordpress prompts me to install again.

What am i doing wrong?

I also tried to use host volumes but to no vail - creates a bind mount and a docker managed volume (Did a docker inspect on container).

So, every time I update the task it resets Wordpress.

Answer (score 4):

> If your container needs access to the original data each time it
>   starts, you require a file system that your containers can connect to
>   regardless of which instance they’re running on. That’s where EFS
>   comes in.
>
> EFS allows you to persist data onto a durable shared file system that
>   all of the ECS container instances in the ECS cluster can use.

[Step-by-step Instructions to Setup an AWS ECS Cluster](https://gist.github.com/duluca/ebcf98923f733a1fdb6682f111b1a832)

[Using Data Volumes in Tasks](http://%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_data_volumes.html)

[Using Amazon EFS to Persist Data from Amazon ECS Containers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-to-persist-data-from-amazon-ecs-containers/)

Comment: Using efs to persist data, The mysql container ends up with a bind(efs folder) and volume. Also, the efs mysql folder on host is empty.